# Magento version upgrade from EE 1.11.2.0 to EE 1.14.2.0

Tags: magento-enterprise, upgrade, ee-1.14.2.0, magento-ee

I need help regarding the Magento upgrade from EE 1.11.2.0 to EE 1.14.2.0, I have the below quires.

1)Can I able to upgrade it directly from current version EE 1.11.2.0 to EE 1.14.2.0 and run all the scripts provided under shell folder like

- **umt113_conflict.php**
- **umt113_redirect.php**
- **url_migration_from_1_13_0_0_to_1_13_0_2.php**
- **url_migration_to_1_13.php**

But there is no information given about the sequece of running them.

2)Or I have to upgrade it in steps like

1. From EE 1.11.2.0 to EE 1.13.0.0 and run the patche provided under shell folder for URL related issue fixes.

   **url_migration_to_1_13.php**
2. then from 1.13.0.0 to 1.13.0.2 and run the below script for URL related issue fixes.

   **url_migration_from_1_13_0_0_to_1_13_0_2.php**
3. then at last from EE 1.13.0.2 to EE 1.14.2.0 and run the below scripts for URL related issues fixes.

   **umt113_redirect.php**

   **umt113_conflict.php**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would open a ticket with Magento support to confirm what your plan should be. But I can answer the following:

To be 100% safe you could first upgrade to 1.13 then you only have to run the url_migration_to_1_13.php. The other script is only for that short upgrade for that version change. You can then run the remainder of the scripts, then run your 1.14.2.1 upgrade.

However, please check with Magento support FIRST to confirm that you still have to do this. You maybe able to to upgrade directly to 1.14.2.1 without the scripts now. (Again, confirm with Magento support, they will give you a detailed plan)

Comment: Thanks brentwpeterson :) for your reply and suggestions sure will try your suggested solution once and also will check with Magento support.

Comment: @Mage_Dev Please accept the answer if you find it acceptable so it will close out the question.

Comment: brentwpeterson: Did u get chance to confirm with Magento support about the plan should be, I have done the direct upgrade but don't have an idea regarding the order of scripts to be run to fix the URL related issues. i.e. umt113_conflict.php, umt113_redirect.php. Please suggest.

Comment: It is up to you to confirm with Magento support, it is your project!